# If $f(z)$ is a nonconstant entire function that is not a polynomial, does $g(z) = f(1/z)$ have an essential singularity at 0?

Tags: complex-analysis

This is mostly a sanity check as I'm now learning how to work with singularities but I feel very uncertain about what I'm able to prove. Anyway, let $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be entire with $f(z)$ not a polynomial. Since $f$ is not a polynomial, we have that $$\lim_{z \to \infty} f(z) \neq \infty$$ If the limit was some finite value, it would follow that $f$ is bounded and thus, that $f$ is constant, contradicting our hypothesis that $f$ is nonconstant. Therefore, the limit does not exist. If we take $g(z) = f( 1 / z)$, $g$ is definitely analytic for $z \neq 0$ and $0$ is necessarily an essential singularity. This has some interesting consequences about the behavior of $f$ for large $|z|$ but I still feel unsure about the methods I used. Does this seem correct? Thank you!

Comment: Remember if a Laurent expansion has infinitely many terms, you have an essential singularity there.

Comment: @SeanNemetz So if f can be expanded as a power series, f(1/z) would have infinitely many terms of negative power in its Laurent expansion and that would be g's unique Laurent expansion, right? That seems like it would really quickly imply that it has an essential singularity at 0. Thank you!

Comment: $g(z)=f(1/z)$ is analytic on $\Bbb{C}^*$, it is bounded on $|z|> 1$, if it has a pole of order $k$ at $z=0$ then $g(z)-\sum_{n=1}^k c_n z^{-n}$ is a bounded entire function, thus it is constant so that $f(z)=C+\sum_{n=1}^k c_n z^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $f(z)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ for all $z$. Since $f$ is not constant and not a polynomial we have that $a_n \ne 0$ for infinitely many $n$.

The Laurent expansion of $g$ around $0$ is given by

$$g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{z^n}.$$

Can you proceed to show that $0$ is an  essential singularity of $g$ ?